# Ordering canvases in HTML

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to achieve this design in my HTML page.
[image]

Where in Positions [1,2,3] I have 6 canvases in each overlayed on the top of each other. (Position 1 has 6 canvases, Position 2 has 6, ...) this is because I need to show 6 images on top of each other with some opacity.

I had my code working for one canvas in each position, but when adding the other canvases, I don't get it the right way. I got it like this:[image]

Of course, each position has 6 canvases as I wanted, but it doesn't appear in the right place

This is my code:

```
<div class="container">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

                <div class="row" style="position:absolute;">

                    <canvas id="canvas_sagittal_channel_1"
                            style="z-index: 1; position:absolute; left:0; top:0; opacity: 0"></canvas>
                    <canvas id="canvas_sagittal_channel_2"
                            style="z-index: 2; position:absolute; left:0; top:0; opacity: 0"></canvas>
                    <canvas id="canvas_sagittal_channel_3"
                            style="z-index: 3; position:absolute; left:0; top:0; opacity: 0"></canvas>
                    <canvas id="canvas_sagittal_channel_4"
                            style="z-index: 4; position:absolute; left:0; top:0; opacity: 0"></canvas>
                    <canvas id="canvas_sagittal_channel_5"
                            style="z-index: 5; position:absolute; left:0; top:0; opacity: 0"></canvas>
                    <canvas id="canvas_sagittal_channel_6"
                            style="z-index: 6; position:absolute; left:0; top:0; opacity: 0"></canvas>

                </div>

                <div class="row" style="position:absolute;">
                    <input type="range" min="0" id="range_sagittal" value="0" oninput="sagittal_range_change()"
                           onchange="sagittal_range_change()">
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

                <div class="row" style="position:absolute;">

                    <canvas id="canvas_coronal_channel_1"
                            style="z-index: 1; position:absolute; left:0; top:0; opacity: 0"></canvas>
                    <canvas id="canvas_coronal_channel_2"
                            style="z-index: 2; position:absolute; left:0; top:0; opacity: 0"></canvas>
                    <canvas id="canvas_coronal_channel_3"
                            style="z-index: 3; position:absolute; left:0; top:0; opacity: 0"></canvas>
                    <canvas id="canvas_coronal_channel_4"
                            style="z-index: 4; position:absolute; left:0; top:0; opacity: 0"></canvas>
                    <canvas id="canvas_coronal_channel_5"
                            style="z-index: 5; position:absolute; left:0; top:0; opacity: 0"></canvas>
                    <canvas id="canvas_coronal_channel_6"
                            style="z-index: 6; position:absolute; left:0; top:0; opacity: 0"></canvas>

                </div>

                <div class="row" style="position:absolute;">
                    <input type="range" min="0" id="range_coronal" value="0" oninput="coronal_range_change()"
                           onchange="coronal_range_change()">
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

                <div class="row" style="position:absolute;">

                    <canvas id="canvas_dorsal_channel_1"
                            style="z-index: 1; position:absolute; left:0; top:0; opacity: 0"></canvas>
                    <canvas id="canvas_dorsal_channel_2"
                            style="z-index: 2; position:absolute; left:0; top:0; opacity: 0"></canvas>
                    <canvas id="canvas_dorsal_channel_3"
                            style="z-index: 3; position:absolute; left:0; top:0; opacity: 0"></canvas>
                    <canvas id="canvas_dorsal_channel_4"
                            style="z-index: 4; position:absolute; left:0; top:0; opacity: 0"></canvas>
                    <canvas id="canvas_dorsal_channel_5"
                            style="z-index: 5; position:absolute; left:0; top:0; opacity: 0"></canvas>
                    <canvas id="canvas_dorsal_channel_6"
                            style="z-index: 6; position:absolute; left:0; top:0; opacity: 0"></canvas>

                </div>

                <div class="row" style="position:absolute;">
                    <input type="range" min="0" id="range_dorsal" value="0" oninput="dorsal_range_change()"
                           onchange="dorsal_range_change()">
                </div>


            </div>

            <div id="3d_visualizer" class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"
                 style="text-align: center; padding: 70px 0; border: 3px solid black">

                {% include 'components/visualizers/interactive_search_visualizer.html' %}

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="row" style="text-align: center">
            Mouse position:
            <label id="mouse_x">X = 0</label>,
            <label id="mouse_y">Y = 0</label>,
            <label id="mouse_z">Z = 0</label>

            , Selected_position:


            <label id="selected_position_x">X = 0</label>,
            <label id="selected_position_y">Y = 0</label>,
            <label id="selected_position_z">Z = 0</label>

        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: can you post your css file ? or make fiddle with your result?

Comment: please share your full html code

Comment: I am not using any css files here just bootstrap. This is the complete code without the Javascript which is very very long and not really connected to the design. I mean I am not changing the design in javascript, I am just loading the images using the scripts